# Get the optimised variables in fminsearch

Tags: r, fminsearch

When using the `fminsearch` function of the neldermead package

```
library(neldermead)

foo <- function(x){
  -exp(-x**2)
}
sol <- fminsearch(fun = foo, x0 = -10)
```

How can I get the optimum values?

I see I can print `sol` and that this gives the correct value:

```
> sol

Number of Estimated Variable(s): 1

Estimated Variable(s):
  Initial Final
1     -10     0
```

But I would need to store that value in a variable. The examples in the documentation do not say how to access to that value, so I guess it is trivial, but I don't find the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the above answer is correct, my understanding is that you need

```
neldermead.get(sol, "xopt")
```

as `sol` is a `neldermead` object, see the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neldermead/neldermead.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Nils ! Just for curiosity, was it possible to see this `xopt` field by inspecting the output object? It is not in names(sol), for instance. Or it is only in the documentation?

Comment: Not at my computer right now but when checking earlier I couldn't find it in the output object via `names`, nor via tab complete in R studio. Only figured it out from the docs myself.